# Two one-side represented relationships on same entities interpreted as the same relationship

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities, Book and Author.

A book has an author, and an author has a favourite book though this is obviously not the same relation.

So, we have:

- A book has an author and that author has many books (1-m);
- An author has a favourite book and a book has been favourited by one author [yes, let's admit it can't be favourited by 2 authors] (1-1).

Each time, I only want to to represent the first part of the relationship in the entity, because I don't need the second part.

How can I represent this relationship using EF Core? Because Ef Core tends to think that the first part of the second relation is the end part of the first par of the first relation => 1-[m][1-]1.

```
public class Book
{
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public Book FavouriteBook { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't work because EF Core think they are both part of the same 1-1 relationship.

`Book.Author` isn't the author that favourited the book. `Author.FavouriteBook` isn't one of the book the author wrote.

I can't use the `ModelBuilder` because each time I don't have the counterpart of the relation.

Comment: Your tables have 1-M and 1-1 relations but your entities only show a 1-1 relation. `Book.Author` is just one end of *some* relation. Without any other configuration EF Core rightly assumes it's a 1-1 relation with `FavouriteBook`. `each time I don't have the counterpart of the relation.` that would be a `Books` property on `Author`

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't want to have other properties on my entities, so I'd like to know if there are some available configuration to tell EF Core those aren't the same relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use the `ModelBuilder` because each time I don't have the counterpart of the relation.

You can, and you should use the fluent API to map (configure) the desired relationships. Relationship configuration allows you to specify the navigation property (or *no property*) of each end, e.g.

```
// Book.Author 1..N Author(no navigation property)
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasOne(book => book.Author);
    .WithMany();

// Author.FavouriteBook 1..1 Book(no navigation property)
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasOne(author => author.FavouriteBook)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Author>("FavouriteBookId");
```

Note the `HasForeignKey` call with generic type argument. This usually is always needed for one-to-one relationships mainly to specify which end is the dependent (via the generic type argument). For one-to-many the one side is always the principal and the many side is always the dependent, so no such configuration is needed.

Fore more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api).

Comment: Yes, I didn't correctly expressed myself when I said "I can't use the `ModelBuilder`". Ok, I wasn't aware of the `WithMany()` and `WithOne()` without arguments. Thanks!